# Format {0:N} return null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, format

I have this on my view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.ExpenseSummaryList[k].AMOUNT_CZ,"{0:N}")`
```

and in model

```
[Column("AMOUNT_CZ")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public double? AMOUNT_CZ { get; set; }
```

When I submit If AMOUNT_CZ is more than 999.00 like 1,850.00 . AMOUNT_CZ will be null.Because of commas(,).
My question is why it happen and is there other format that display same as format "{0:N}" but wont return commas(,) in model.

Comment: Check {0:F2}, this format is without comma

Comment: But number will be better in version with comma.But thank you

Comment: Is it solved your problem?

Comment: No ,Becauce i want it will be with comma without help of javascript or hidden field

Comment: If you want a comma (meaning it will not bind to `double`) you will need to write you own custom `ModelBinder`

Comment: Thank you  Stephen Muecke .It help me